# css @support not working on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, web, mobile, cross-browser

i'm trying to use the `backdrop-filter` property on browsers that support it and `background-color` on browsers where it is not supported.

```
  .backdrop-filter {
    background-color: black;
  }

@supports (
  (backdrop-filter: blur(8px)) or (-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px))
) {
  .backdrop-filter {
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  }
}
```

The above code works fine on web browsers but I don't get the desired results on mobile browsers.
Did I get the syntax wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Support for `@supports` on mobile seems quite limited: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_supports_selector

Comment: Thanks @Sirko. Is there an alternative route I can take to achieve this?

Comment: The JavaScript API seems to be better supported: https://caniuse.com/css-supports-api so maybe have a small script at the start of your page to detect support and set some basic class on body.